# How to show solution of linear dynamical system is bounded?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

> Consider the time-dependent linear system in $\mathbb{R}^n$ $$\dot{x} = A x + b(t)$$ where $b: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous. Suppose $$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} b(t) = 0$$ and that all eigenvalues of $A$ have negative real parts. Prove that regardless of the initial condition, the solution $x(t)$ approaches $0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$.

My try:

We know the unique solution satisfying the initial condition $x(0) = x_0$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$ is

$$
x(t) = e^{At}x_0 + \int_0^t e^{A(t-s)}b(s)d(s)
$$

Also, we know that when all eigenvalues have negative real parts, $\|e^{At}x_0\| \leq Me^{-c}\|x_0\|$ for all $t$ where $\|\cdot\|=\|\cdot\|_2$ and some positive $c$ and $M$. Therefore taking the norm from both sides and using triangle inequality we have:

$$
\|x(t)\| = \|e^{At}x_0 + \int_0^t e^{A(t-s)}b(s)d(s)\|
$$

$$
\|x(t)\| \leq \|e^{At}x_0\| + \|\int_0^t e^{A(t-s)}b(s)d(s)\|
$$

$$
\|x(t)\| \leq Me^{-c}\|x_0\| + \|\int_0^t e^{A(t-s)}b(s)d(s)\|
$$

$$
\|x(t)\| \leq Me^{-c}\|x_0\| + \int_0^t \|e^{A(t-s)}\|\|b(s)\|d(s)
$$

I do not know how to handle the integral part.

Comment: If the eigenvalues have negative real parts, can't one immediately conclude that the system is BIBO stable? If the input is continuous and eventually dies down, can't  one conclude that it is bounded?

Comment: Could you provide with me an example?

Comment: I think taking a good look at [Antsaklis & Michel](https://books.google.com/books?id=Irr0W8s4rKUC) would be wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out, we have
\begin{align}
\|e^{tA} f\|_2  \leq& \|e^{tA}\|_\text{op}\|f\|_2 = \sqrt{\lambda_\max(e^{tA^*} e^{tA})}\|f\|_2\leq e^{-ct}\|f\|_2
\end{align}
for some $c>0$.

Then it follows
\begin{align}
\|x(t)\| \leq& \left(e^{-ct}\|x_0\|+ \int^t_0 e^{-c(t-s)}\|b(s)\|\ ds \right)\\
=&\  \left(e^{-ct}\|x_0\|+ \int^{t_0}_0 e^{-c(t-s)}\|b(s)\|\ ds+ \int^t_{t_0} e^{-c(t-s)}\|b(s)\|\ ds \right).
\end{align}
Since $b(t)$ is continuous and $b(t) \rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$, then $\|b(t)\|\leq M$ for all $t$ and there exists $t_0$ such that for all $t>t_0$ we have that $\|b(t)\| <\varepsilon$. Hence it follows
\begin{align}
\|x(t)\| \leq& \left(e^{-ct}\|x_0\| + M\int^{t_0}_0 e^{-c(t-s)}\ ds + \varepsilon\int^t_{t_0} e^{-c(t-s)}\ ds \right)\\
\leq&\ \left(e^{-ct}\|x_0\|+ \frac{M}{c}(e^{-c(t-t_0)}-e^{-ct}) + \frac{\varepsilon}{c} \right)
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\limsup_{t\rightarrow \infty} \|x(t)\| \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{c}
\end{align}
for any $\varepsilon>0$. Thus $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \|x(t)\| = \limsup_{t\rightarrow \infty} \|x(t)\| = 0$.

Comment: Can you explain why $\|e^{tA}\|_\text{op} = \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(e^{tA^\ast} e^{At})}$?

Comment: @Sepide Note that you are using the Euclidean norm on both domain and range, so the corresponding operator norm is given by the Frobenius 2-norm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm

Comment: Actually, $\|e^{tA}\|_\text{op} = \|e^{tA}\|_2 \leq \|e^{tA}\|_F$, not equality. I made a slight error, but it doesn't affect anything in the argument.

Comment: I am not using Euclidean norm, $\|\cdot\|$ can be any norm. Can we solve that we we suppose other norms. I am asking for my curiosity.

Comment: In finite dimension, I think all norms are equivalent.

Comment: Could you revise that?

Comment: Okay, I replaced the equality with an inequality.